# How does python access object attributes under the hood?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, attributes

I want to understand the exact actions order when python is accessing object attributes. What I mean: I know that at first `__getattribute__` method is called, I also know that object dictionary has priority over class dictionary, therefore python checks object's dictionary earlier than class dictionary, then I know that data-descriptors have so high priority and even if they are already rewritten in object dictionary but kept in class dictionary they will be used. Finally I know that if somewhere AttributeError occurs `__getattr__` method will be called considering it was implemented. So, can someone explain me the exact order of actions for accessing object or class attribute in python?

p. s.
If I made a mistake, please correct me.

Comment: You wrote what you do know. What do you **not** know? You already seem to know the attribute resolution order, I'm not sure what is left to explain

Comment: I dont know the order and I am not sure I'm right